# Center text while on position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, css-position

I am working on a team roster page. I was inspired by https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/football/first-team/players and tried to replicate it as much as possible,for some practise.The problem i have ran into,is that to make their lastname visible in the background,i am using **position:absolute** and **paddign-top** to place it where i want to,but i can't seem to manage,to find a proper way to **[place the lastname in the exact center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCAW3.jpg)** of the div

```js
const player = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('player'));
const lastname_background = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('lastname-background'));
const info = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('info'));
const hidden_stats = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-stats'));


player.forEach(i=>i.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{
    const index = player.indexOf(i)
    lastname_background[index].style.paddingTop = "25vh";
    info[index].style.paddingTop = "31vh";
    lastname_background[index].style.transition = "0.4s";
    info[index].style.transition = "0.4s";
    hidden_stats[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    hidden_stats[index].style.transition = "1s";
}))

player.forEach(i=>i.addEventListener('mouseout',()=>{
    const index = player.indexOf(i)
    lastname_background[index].style.paddingTop = "33vh";
    info[index].style.paddingTop = "40vh";
    lastname_background[index].style.transition = "0.4s";
    info[index].style.transition = "0.4s";
    hidden_stats[index].style.visibility = "hidden";
}))
```

```css
.page-title {
    font-size: 2.7vw;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -50px 25px -10px #1A2434;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -50px 25px -10px #1A2434;
}

.outside-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 90%
}

.players {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

h3{
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #d14f51;
}

.player{
    height: 50vh;
    width: 25%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -150px 120px -15px #1A2434;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -150px 120px -15px #1A2434;
}

.player:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.info {
    padding-top: 40vh;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    z-index: 9;
}

.inline1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.7vw;
}

.hidden-stats{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}

.inline2{
    width: 7vw;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.308);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 1vh;
}

.stat-title{
    font-size: 0.5vw;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
}
.position{
    font-size: 0.8vw;
}


.lastname-background {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 33vh;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.lastname-background p {
    font-style: italic;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.15;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h4 class="page-title">First team</h4>
    <div class="outside-container">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Keepers</h3>
            <div class="players goalkeepers">
                <div class="player" style="background-image: url('<%= player.image %>');">
    <div class="lastname-background">
            <p>player lastname</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="info" >
        <div class="inline1" id="number">player.number</div>
        <div class="inline1" id="firstname">player.firstname</div>
        <div class="inline1" id="lastname">player.lastname</div>
        <div class="position">player.position</div>

        <div class="hidden-stats">
            <div class="inline2">
                <div class="stat-title">Birthday</div>
                <div>player birthday</div>
            </div>

            <div class="inline2">
                <div class="stat-title">Appearances</div>
                <div>player appearances</div>
            </div>

            <div class="inline2">
                <div class="stat-title">Γκολ</div>
                <div>player goals</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

            </div>
            <h3>Defenders</h3>
            <div class="players defenders">

            </div>
            <h3>Midfielders</h3>
            <div class="players midfielders">

            </div>
            <h3>Forwards</h3>
            <div class="players forwards">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to `.player` to make it the reference for the absolutely positioned child element.

Comment: I added position:relative  to the player and then width:100% to the lastname and then text-align: center; to the paragraph and it worked,thank you!!